# Python Pydantic converting a model to send in a requests payload with None values

Tags: python, json, pydantic

I have a pydantic model below.

```
part_a = CreatePartRequest(
    category="Mud Motor Power",
    component_type="Test",
    part_number="PS66101781",
    part_attribute={
        "belly_honed": "NO",
        "bottom_rubber_cutback": 18,
        "coating_mfg": None,
        "rubber_type": None,
        "solid": None,
        "stages": 7.9,
        "top_rubber_cutback": 12,
    },
)
```

This model has None values within the part_attributes dict which I would like to convert to null so it would be an acceptable payload to be sent to an API. I don't want to drop these keys.

I am using the below to send in the payload but I am having issues with either the None values not being converted to null, or it being converted to a json string rather than a json dict.

The API expects a list of dicts as the payload so something like `[ {} ]`

```
response = requests.post(
        f"{api_base_url}/parts",
        data=[part_a_request.model_dump()],
        headers=api_token_header,
    )
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

The above results in a 422 error because the None values don't get converted to null.

I then tried `json=[part_a_request.model_dump_json()]` which resulted in the None values being converted to null but the json was converted to a string rather than a list of dicts. I could drop the extra quotes but that just seems like bad code. Is there nothing built in to convert my pydantic model as an acceptable payload that takes into account of None values?

Comment: Try `json=[part_a_request.model_dump()]`. You don't need `model_dump_json` there